# Adding custom taxonomy in same menu place with two custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I have registered 2 post types:

```
register_post_type( 'post_type1' , $args1 );
register_post_type( 'post_type2' , $args2 );
```

And I've registered a custom taxonomy associated with the second post type:

```
register_taxonomy('post-type2-category', 'post_type2', array('hierarchical' => true, 'show_in_menu' => true, 'label' => esc_html__('My taxonomy', 'my_lang_slug'), 'singular_label' => esc_html__('My taxonomy', 'my_lang_slug'), 'rewrite' => true, 'slug' => 'post-type2-cat', 'show_in_nav_menus' => false));
```

I've also put in the `$args2` variable, for second custom post type

```
'show_in_menu' => 'edit.php?post_type=post_type1',
```

So that my second custom post type appears in the same admin menu as the first one. But the problem is that now my taxonomy isn't showing. If I put the object type to first custom post type, then it shows before my second CPT. But I need the taxonomy only for my second CPT. I've tried with `add_submenu_page();` but had no luck.

Is this possible?

Comment: Second one overrides the first post type. `add_submenu_page()` won't help you here.  I guess you need to compromise either one here.  Than add it separately

Comment: Yeah, I decided that I'll ditch the second one, and use taxonomy to differentiate between the two. Less hassle.

Comment: Yes.  That's better way to go. Good luck.